# get the current HEAD version of a CVS file on the server

Tags: linux, cvs, rcs

Using the `rlog` command I can analyze the commit log to a file on the CVS *server* itself (that is, directly accessing the file ending in "`,v`"). That's fine.

Is there a similar command line utility that prints the current HEAD version of that file to stdout?

I need this for a custom CVS status utility (something like [ViewVC](http://www.viewvc.org/), but made specifically for a certain repository) that will be written in PHP.

Comment: Didn't your mother teach you to run away from CVS ;)

Comment: my grandpa passed it on to me ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print the content of the file that would be checked out, just use `co -p filename`.  That will print a small header including the revision number to stderr, and the content of the file to stdout.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want `cvs log filename`. Not sure buy you might need to do `cvs update filename` first.

Comment: I need a command on the server, something like `some_utility /path/to/repository/file.c,v`